# Oracle procedure execute immediate

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a stored procedure under SYS, which uses the `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` command to execute `alter object compile`.  But I am getting the below error.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE comp_inv
is   
   CURSOR empCursor IS 
      SELECT object_type, 
             owner,object_name 
        from dba_objects
       where status = 'INVALID' 
         and object_type in ('PACKAGE','FUNCTION','PROCEDURE');    
BEGIN
   FOR i_rec IN empCursor LOOP       
      execute immediate 'alter ' ||i_rec.object_type|| ' ' || 
                         i_rec.owner || '.' || i_rec.object_name || ' compile';  
   END LOOP;
END;
/
```

> ```
> SQL> exec comp_inv;
> ERROR:
> ORA-24344: success with compilation error
> ORA-06512: at "SYS.COMP_INV", line 8
> ORA-06512: at line 1
>
>
> Warning: PL/SQL compilation errors.
>
> SQL> show errors procedure comp_inv;
> No errors.
> ```

Comment: select * from USER_ERRORS where NAME = i_rec.object_name and type = i_rec.object_type; You can use this in your code itself, so you display the errors immediately. As it is execute via a proc, I guess sho errors might not display them.

Comment: You should *NEVER EVER* create objects under the SYS account. If you make a mistake, you'll likely make your system unusable, and Oracle support probably will refuse to assist you if you made changes to the SYS schema.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the standard Oracle package `DBMS_UTILITY` and it's procedure `COMPILE_SCHEMA()` which gives you standard way to recompile invalidated objects. It's worth to use it for many reasons, in particular it allows you to keep compile settings.

Comment: @Nicholas Krasnov I know all this above. But everything I see in the original post is the try to make a recompile using user-defined procedure created in SYS schema - not the best way I think.

Comment: Believe me if you use this function all of your stored programs will be recompiled and some times it will cause problems(ie system down) S use it carefully and in proper time!

Comment: @hmmftg Yes, complete recompile can really cause system down, so Oracle provides compile_all parameter to control it (unfortunately it has "true" value by default and you are 100% rigt - this is a trap).

Answer (score 3):

In your situation the error simply means that some schema objects cannot be recompiled, for some reason - procedure is executed successfully, but some objects you are trying to recompile cannot be recompiled. For example:

```
create table t1(col1 number);

create or replace procedure p2(p_in in number) is
  l_res number;
begin
  select count(1)
    into l_res
    from t1;
end;
```

Determine if there is something "INVALID" there:

```
column object_type format a10;
column object_name format a10;
column status      fromat a10;

select object_type
     , object_name 
     , status
  from dba_objects
 where status = 'INVALID' 
   and object_type in ('PACKAGE','FUNCTION','PROCEDURE'); 

 no rows selected
```

Invalidate `P2` procedure:

```
alter table t1 add (col2 number);

column object_type format a10;
column object_name format a10;
column status      fromat a10;

select object_type
     , object_name 
     , status
  from dba_objects
 where status = 'INVALID' 
   and object_type in ('PACKAGE','FUNCTION','PROCEDURE');

OBJECT_TYP OBJECT_NAM STATUS
---------- ---------- -------
PROCEDURE  P2         INVALID
```

Recompiling:

```
exec comp_inv

anonymous block completed
```

Recompilation went successfully:

```
column object_type format a10;
column object_name format a10;
column status      fromat a10;

select object_type
     , object_name 
     , status
  from dba_objects
 where status = 'INVALID' 
   and object_type in ('PACKAGE','FUNCTION','PROCEDURE');

 no rows selected
```

Invalidate our `P2` procedure so it cannot be compiled:

```
create or replace procedure p2(p_in in number) is
  l_res number;
begin
  invalid_operator;
end;
/

PROCEDURE P2 compiled
Errors: check compiler log
```

Check for invalid objects:

```
column object_type format a10;
column object_name format a10;
column status      fromat a10;

select object_type
     , object_name 
     , status
  from dba_objects
 where status = 'INVALID' 
   and object_type in ('PACKAGE','FUNCTION','PROCEDURE');

OBJECT_TYP OBJECT_NAM STATUS
---------- ---------- -------
PROCEDURE  P2         INVALID
```

Trying to recompile that procedure:

```
exec comp_inv

ORA-24344: success with compilation error
ORA-06512: at "SYS.COMP_INV", line 11
ORA-06512: at line 1
24344. 00000 -  "success with compilation error"
```

As it has already been said by @OracleUser check one of the  `*_errors` data dictionary view, to see if there is something in it. It'll provide you with information needed to *eliminate the threat*.

```
column owner format a10;
column name  format a10;
column type  format a10;
column text  format a60;

select owner
     , name
     , type
     , text
  from dba_errors

OWNER      NAME       TYPE      TEXT  
------ ---------- ------------------------------------------------------------
NK         P2         PROCEDURE  PLS-00201: identifier 
                                             'INVALID_OPERATOR' must be declared 
NK         P2         PROCEDURE  PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

Secondly, as @Frank Schmitt correctly pointed out in his comment to your question never, ever create user objects of any kind in the `SYS` schema. If you need to store some administrative stored procedures or other objects somewhere, dedicate a different user for that with appropriate privileges and roles granted, or as a last resort use `SYSTEM`(which is not recommended either) schema.

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE comp_inv
is   
   CURSOR empCursor IS 
      SELECT object_type, 
             owner,object_name 
        from dba_objects
       where status = 'INVALID' 
         and object_type in ('PACKAGE','FUNCTION','PROCEDURE');    
BEGIN
   FOR i_rec IN empCursor LOOP
      BEGIN
        execute immediate 'alter ' ||i_rec.object_type|| ' ' || 
                         i_rec.owner || '.' || i_rec.object_name || ' compile';
      EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
         FOR I IN (select * from DBA_ERRORS where NAME = i_rec.object_name and owner = i_rec.owner AND type = i_rec.object_type)
         LOOP
                DBMS_OUPT.PUT_LINE(I.line || ' ' || I.text);
         END LOOP;
      END;

   END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

this might be what you need.

```
    exec dbms_utility.compile_schema('SCOTT');
```

off course you need proper rights to execute that

Comment: Actually you better connect as Sys user!